# Migrate Data from Neo4j to SQL

Tags: neo4j, data-migration

Hi I am using neo4j in my application and my structure is as following:

1. I am using **Embedded Graph** API
2. I have several databases that I point to using a pool that I maintain in my application **eg->** db1, db2, db3, ..... db100
3. When I want to access a particular database I point to it using **new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("Path to db(n)")**
4. The problem is that when the connection pool count increases the **RAM size** being consumed by the application **keep increasing** and **breaks down the application** at a point of limit.
5. So I am Thinking of migrating from **Neo4j to some other Database**.
6. Additionally only **a small part of my database** is utilizing the **graph structure**.

**One way for migration is that I write a script for it. Is there any better option?**

**My another question is what is the best Database so that my structure can be maintained.**

**Other view-point that I am thinking about is I can keep part of my data into Neo4j and shift another part to some other database.**

If anything is unclear I can clarify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try the gremling xml exports/imports via graphML. i used this and a little bit of programming to import SQL data into neo4j. here's a link to import but i'm sure you can find in the gremlin manual the export command: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-load-a-sample-graph

Comment: Mind if I address #4? The RAM size increase is most likely tied to the Cache that Neo4j creates. Have you tried turning off caching in the neo4j.properties if you don't want the RAM size to increase?

Comment: @Nicholas - But that would degrade performance ... right?

Answer (score 1):

An EmbeddedGraphDatabase instance is *not* the equivalent of a "connection" in SQL. It's designed to run a long time (days, months). Hence starting/stopping is costly.

What is the use case for having hundreds of separate databases in the same JVM?

Comment: Hi Mattias, Thanks for your answer. I understand that an EmbeddedGraphDatabase instance is designed to run for a longer period and that only is the reason for failure. Use case is like we maintain a separate hierarchy(a kind of bank) for each of our clients and the structure however is more clear in design. Moreover each client can maintains its own hierarchy.

Comment: Would it be possible for all clients to live in the same database, and each have their own separate root nodes? Indexes would be global though... but their results could be filtered based on client.

Comment: Yes it could be done but still it would still require lots of restructuring and migrate data for nearly 1000s of clients :(  .... so practically no lesser tedious than migration

Answer (score 1):

Your lots of small databases will perform poorly as the graphdb is designed to hold the whole datamodel on a single host.

Do you run a single JVM per database?

You can control the amount of memory used by neo4j by providing the correct properties for memory mapping and also use the gcr cache from neo4j-enterprise and control the cache size-property variables.

I think it still makes sense to keep the graph part in Neo4j and only move the non-graphy part.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for you answer. I have used a single JVM instance for instantaniating all the databases over which I have a Thrift layer.