# What cautions should be taken while Using Neo4j?

Tags: database-design, neo4j

**Neo4j** as we know is a **Graph Based NoSql Database**.
But sometimes we decide to use Neo4j in our application but find out that it creates more problems than solving them.
How Should we design the neo4j database that it would be a good use?

**To start with:**

1. Prefer to use Neo4j while your structure is more Graph Based, like Social Networking.
2. Avoid to make Multiple databases for different situations like the problem occurred in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673331/migrate-data-from-neo4j-to-sql)
3. Prefer to make use of self generated NodeId to identify node.

Comment: Yes the question is how should you design your database in neo4j that it will be a good use of neo4j

Comment: Sounds like a little too generic of a question. Design as in structuring your data in the graph model? Your mentioned problems doesn't have much to do with the modelling though. I can't tell what kind of answers you are looking for.